# Inhomogeneous Compound Poisson process

Tags: simulation

I need to use a compound Poisson process with time-varying jump intensity. Mathematica has the function of compound Poisson process as well as inhomogeneous Poisson process, but no combination of these two. Is it possible to create such a process? In addition, how to create contemporaneous compound processes with different jump distributions, that is two jump processes controlled by the same Poisson counter. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sufficiently familiar with these distributions to give you a concrete answer, but if these distributions can be constructed from more simpler ones, you should have a look at `MixtureDistribution`, `ParameterMixtureDistribution`, and `TransformedDistribution`. Even more ways to modify distributions can be found [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DerivedDistributions.html).